# Where to start with Linux Kernel Modules?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

A little background, I'm a CMPE Student currently in an Operating Systems class. I have some basic knowledge of C coding but am more comfortable with C++ (taken about 3 semesters of that). Other than that, never had any other formal training in coding. Also, I've got a basic understanding of the linux environment.

I am working on a project that requires me and my team to code a linux kernel module that can do the following:

- echoes data passed from user-level processes by printing the data received to the kernel log
- is able to pass data from one user process to another.
- must be possible to use the kernel module as an inter-process communication abstraction. module should provide for situations where a sender posts data to it but no receiver is waiting.module must cover the situation where a receiver asks for data but there is no data available.
- module must cover the situation where a receiver asks for data but there is no data available.
- must be a limit in the buffer capacity in your module.

Now I don't know how difficult this seems to those with a background in programming, but this seems like an impossibly complicated task for someone in my position.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Coded, Compiled, Inserted, and Removed the basic "hello world" linux kernel module successfully
2. Read through about the first 4 or 5 chapters of [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/)
3. Read through a few stackoverflow posts, none of which seem to be able to direct me to where I need to go.

So finally here's my question: Can someone please point me in the direction that I need to go with this? I don't even know where to being to find commands to use for reading in user-level process data and I need somewhere to start me off. TLPD was great for insight on the topic but isn't helping me get to the point where I will have a workable project to turn in. In the past, I would learn off of reading source code and reverse engineering, is there anywhere I can find something like that? Any and all help is appreciated.

-Will

Comment: You'll probably want to expose one or more virtual files on /dev or something, and design an API of file reads and writes on this virtual file.

Comment: That sounds great if it weren't for the fact that I don't know what any of that means, haha. I guess I'm a little bit more amateur than I led you to believe. Any chance that you could put that into 5 year old speak?

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide is a pretty good resource.  From the sounds of it, something like a character device might work best for your purposes, but I'm not sure if you have other constraints.

Another direction I might consider (though this could be a bad path) is to look at examples in the Linux kernel for a kernel module that has similar functionality.  I don't have a good example offhand, but perhaps look through `/drivers/char/`.

Comment: There were no other constraints that we were given. Everything my teacher told me was what I wrote down in my original post. I'll take a look in that folder though. Thanks for that tip. So whatever .c file I can find in that folder has code that is valid for a module as well? I'm mainly concerned about what are the functions that I can/cannot use to accomplish the task. I know how IPC is supposed to work on a theoretical standpoint from lecture but I never knew what the proper syntax was.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is pretty much the same as a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).

Read chapter three of [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).
(But don't just copy the [scull pipe example](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/ldd-examples/scull/) …)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm reading through the pipe stuff and looking at the sample code, I can follow the logic of how it works. I understand what the definitions of these functions are but here's one thing I'm getting hung up on. How do I actually get the process to come and use the pipe? Where does the code say "here's the process, now process come here and use the O_WRONLY flag to write something"? I think I may be missing some fundamental knowledge here.

Comment: To ask a question, please use the "Ask Question" button.